# Microsoft Access creating a query that finds records between 10 and 11 months ago

Tags: ms-access

I created a query that could miss 29 and 30th days of the months that is like

```
">DateAdd("m";-11;Now()) And <DateAdd("m";-10;Now())"
```

please help me to write a query that is not missing the 29th and 30 th days of the month

Comment: The easiest way is to remember that the last day of the month is always the day before the first day of the month following. With that in mind this will give you the last day of the previous month `DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()),0) `- I'll let you work it out from there.

Comment: Do you define "10 months ago" as "exactly 10 months ago" (so from Nov 12, 2018 it is Jan 12, 2018) or do you define it as the "start of the month from 10+ months ago" (so from Nov 12, 2018 it is Jan 1, 2018) or as "start of the month from 10- months ago" (so from Nov 12, 2018 it is Feb 1, 2018)? What you already have should work correctly for the first case, although depending on your exact definition you may need to use `>=` and/or `<=` instead of `>` and `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
>DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date())-11;1) And <DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date())-9;0)
```

The 0 (zero) day will return the last date of the previous month.

Comment: >DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date())-11;1) And <=DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date())-9;0) is okay